# Modify list-comprehension by including two condition

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, nlp, list-comprehension

I have this piece of line :
I have a list of sublist where i want to extract for each subli the element at index -1 (last element) , how can I add the Following condition :

> if index[-1] == " " take the index[0] and if index [-1] is not empty take -1 , how can i modify what I have below:

```
list = [[w.split('\t')[-1] for w in subl]for subl in list_general]
```

here is list_general

```
[['ça\tPRO:DEM\tcela', 'tout\tADV\ttout', 'médecins\tNOM\tmédecin', 'sauf\tPRP\tsauf', 'éventuellement\tADV\téventuellement', 'télétransmission\tNOM\ttélétransmission'], ['de\tPRP\tde', 'plus\tADV\tplus', 'plus\tADV\tplus', 'collègues\tNOM\tcollègue', 'disent\tVER:pres\tdire', 'va\tVER:pres\taller', 'disparaitre\tVER:infi\tdisparaître', 'profit\tNOM\tprofit'], ['apportée\tVER:pper\tapporter', 'cardiologue\tNOM\tcardiologue', 'les\tDET:ART\tle', 'outilis\tNOM\toutilis', 'dont\tPRO:REL\tdont', 'dispose\tVER:pres\tdisposer', 'avis\tNOM\tavis', 'limitée\tVER:pper\tlimiter'], ['pour\tPRP\tpour', 'suivi\tNOM\tsuivi', 'patients\tADJ\tpatient', 'pense\tVER:pres\tpenser', 'grand\tADJ\tgrand', 'part\tNOM\tpart', 'les\tDET:ART\tle', 'patients\tNOM\tpatient', 'peuvent\tVER:pres\tpouvoir', 'avoir\tVER:infi\tavoir', 'rdv\tNOM\trdv', 'rapidement\tADV\trapidement']]
```

Comment: Please provide an example of list_general

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken this shorter sample:

`arr = [["a\tb", "c\td", "e"], ["f"]]`

you can adjust you list-comprehension like this:

`out = [[w.split('\t')[-1] if len(w.split('\t')) > 1 else w.split('\t')[0] for w in subl] for subl in arr]`

Within the comprehension I added a length-check: `len(w.split('\t'))`. If the length is greater then 1, the last argument is taken, otherwise the first (and only) one.

Additionally, don`t use 'list' as variable since it is already a command in python.